# TortoiseSVN temporarily ignore files when checking for modifications

Tags: c#, .net, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

In our project we have `.suo`, `.csproj` files which are committed and while I'm working with project/solution they are often changed. When I issue the command for `Check for modifications` then these files show up. I don't want to ignore the files as they contains metadata which is useful when developing and may be changed by one of the committers(I'm not a committer by the way), but I want them not to show up in the `Check for modifications` command list. Is there a way I can achieve it, but I don't want to have to tell the committer to do any changes on this ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. When you are committing you can ignore, but when you are updating no.